# How to remove white line between two divs

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

geeks! It's probably simply question.. but how can I remove this 'white line' or 'gap' between two divs in the same color?

It's only problem when I have the same background color in the divs. It's not visible when I pick other color. You can see this gap while scrolling.

I was trying to manage with background-color and border but it doesn't works for me or I am doing something wrong..

---

```css
html.fp-enabled,
.fp-enabled body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    /*Avoid flicker on slides transitions for mobile phones #336 */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#sec1, #sec2{
background-color: #ac2022;
}

.section{
 text-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
body{
background-color: transparent;}

.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari<=5 Android<=3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=28 */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fp-slide {
    float: left;
}
.fp-slide, .fp-slidesContainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.fp-slides {
    z-index:1;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; /* Safari<=6 Android<=4.3 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fp-slidesContainer {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.fp-auto-height.fp-section,
.fp-auto-height .fp-slide,
.fp-auto-height .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}

.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive.fp-section,
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-slide,
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-tableCell {
    height: auto !important;
}

/*Only display content to screen readers*/
.fp-sr-only{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullpage.js@3.0.8/dist/fullpage.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="website description...">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>



<div id="fullpage">
  <div id="p1" class="page-section section">
     <div class="slide" id="sec1" data-anchor="slide1">
       <img src="" data-src="" />
       <h3>Section 1</h3>
       <a href=""><p class="view-more">See more</p></a>

     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="p2" class="page-section section">
     <div class="slide" id="sec2" data-anchor="slide1">
       <img src="" data-src="" />
       <h3>Section 2</h3>
       <a href=""><p class="view-more">See more</p></a>
     </div>
  </div>


  <div id="p2" class="page-section section">Some section</div>
  <div id="p3" class="page-section section">Some section</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
 //Navigation
 menu: '#menu',
 lockAnchors: false,
 anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'fifthPage'],
 navigation: true,
 navigationPosition: 'right',
 navigationTooltips: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06',],
 showActiveTooltip: true,
 slidesNavigation: true,
 slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

 //Scrolling
 css3: true,
 scrollingSpeed: 700,
 autoScrolling: true,
 fitToSection: true,
 fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
 scrollBar: false,
 easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
 easingcss3: 'ease',
 loopBottom: false,
 loopTop: false,
 loopHorizontal: true,
 continuousVertical: false,
 continuousHorizontal: false,
 scrollHorizontally: false,
 interlockedSlides: false,
 dragAndMove: false,
 offsetSections: false,
 resetSliders: true,
 fadingEffect: false,
 normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
 scrollOverflow: false,
 scrollOverflowReset: false,
 scrollOverflowOptions: null,
 touchSensitivity: 15,
 bigSectionsDestination: null,

 //Accessibility
 keyboardScrolling: true,
 animateAnchor: true,
 recordHistory: true,

 //Design
 controlArrows: false,
 verticalCentered: true,
 sectionsColor : ['#ccc', '#fff'],
 paddingTop: 0,
 paddingBottom: 0,
 fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
 responsiveWidth: 0,
 responsiveHeight: 0,
 responsiveSlides: false,
 parallax: false,
 parallaxOptions: {type: 'reveal', percentage: 62, property: 'translate'},
 cards: false,
 cardsOptions: {perspective: 100, fadeContent: true, fadeBackground: true},

 //Custom selectors
 sectionSelector: '.section',
 slideSelector: '.slide',

 lazyLoading: true,

 //events
 onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){},
 afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){},
 afterRender: function(){},
 afterResize: function(width, height){},
 afterReBuild: function(){},
 afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){},
 afterSlideLoad: function(section, origin, destination, direction){},
 onSlideLeave: function(section, origin, destination, direction){}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with fullPage.js or even Javascript. It is a CSS issue. 
I've changed your tags and title accordingly.

Comment: sounds like an `inline-block` whitespace issue or possibly a table `border-collapse` issue?

Comment: `fullPage: Fullpage.js version 3 has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a `licenseKey` option. `